# MySQL subtract bigint value as year

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MySQL database which holds one column years_valid_for as bigint and another column completion_date as datetime(6). I have to subtract bigint columns number as years.

e.g. years_valid_for is 4 and completion_date is 2023-06-07. I have to subtract 4 years from 2023-06-07 and get 2019-06-07.

Is it possible? If so, how?

I have tried DATE_SUB function but could not achieve the expected result due to syntax errors

Comment: Try https://dbfiddle.uk/CTeXLFos. You'd use `select date_sub(completion_date, interval years_valid_for year) from your table;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT *, completion_date - INTERVAL years_valid_for YEAR 
FROM mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/oyDXXxfP)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add INTERVAL keyword. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:- DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL value interval)

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(completion_date, INTERVAL years_valid_for YEAR) AS res_date FROM your_table_name
```